# Unir todos os valores no mesmo nível do array, em um mesmo nível

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte `array`:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 30
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 300
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 4000
            [2] => 9000
        )

)
```

Em um `loop`, quero todos os valores de índice `0`, fiquem no mesmo conjunto, ou seja, `[0]([A][0] [B][0] [C][0])`.

Resultado esperado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 4000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 9000
        )

)
```

Existe alguma função **nativa** para isso ?

Caso não, como faria ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Versão Curta

Existe sim:

```
$resultado = array_map(null, $arr["A"], $arr["B"], $arr["C"]);
```

ou:

```
array_unshift($arr, null);
$resultado = call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr);
```

### Versão Longa

Existe de facto uma função nativa que consegue fazer isso e chama se [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) considerando o caso particular de passar `null` como primeiro parâmetro, que corresponde ao callback. Um dos exemplos da [documentação (Exemplo #4)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) tem uma nota interessante face a isto:

> Uma forma interessante de se usar esta função é na construção de um array de arrays, o que pode ser facilmente feito usando NULL como o nome da função callback.

Nesse exemplo o `array_map` é chamado com `null` e com os 3 `arrays` relevantes:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array("um", "dois", "tres", "quatro", "cinco");
$c = array("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco");

$d = array_map(null, $a, $b, $c);
```

Em que o resultado vai construir um array de arrays com um valor de cada um intercaladamente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => um
            [2] => uno
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => dois
            [2] => dos
        )
    ...
```

Aplicando esta ideia ao seu código poderia começar com algo simples indicando cada um dos indices a interpretar, que correspondem aos sub-arrays:

```
$arr = array(
    'A' => array(10,20,30),
    'B' => array(100,200,300),
    'C' => array(1000,4000,9000)
);

$res = array_map(null, $arr["A"], $arr["B"], $arr["C"]);
print_r($res);
```

Que lhe dá a seguinte saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 4000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 9000
        )

)
```

[Veja o resultado no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Vjg6r0)

No entanto acaba por ser rígido pois força não so saber as chaves como a quantidade de elementos que tem. Para contornar este problema pode seguir uma solução um pouco mais abaixo na documentação que coloca `null` no inicio do array com [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unshift.php) e depois expande todos os parâmetros para a função map com [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$arr = array(
    'A' => array(10,20,30),
    'B' => array(100,200,300),
    'C' => array(1000,4000,9000)
);

array_unshift($arr, null);
$res = call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr);
print_r($res);
```

Que lhe dá exatamente a mesma saída.

[Veja esta solução também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/EuKdiS)

### Detalhando `array_unshift` e `call_user_func_array`

O `array_unshift` serve apenas para adicionar um valor ao inicio. Por isso imaginado que tenha um array assim:

```
$arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Ao fazer `array_unshift($arr, null);` ele vai ficar com `null` no inicio, como se tivesse sido construído assim:

```
$arr = Array(null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

O `call_user_func_array` vai pegar na função indicada e chama-la passando como parâmetros todos os valores do array indicado. Imagine que tem o array definido acima:

```
$arr = Array(null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Ao fazer `call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr);` é como se tivesse chamado diretamente o `array_map` da seguinte forma:

```
array_map(null, 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5);
```

Isto não seria possível de fazer manualmente pois a quantidade de parâmetros iria mudar consoante a quantidade de elementos no array, que é na verdade o primeiro exemplo que dei com `array_map(null, $arr["A"], $arr["B"], $arr["C"]);`.

Comment: O `array_unshift` serve para jogar todos os arrays para 1 nível só !?

Comment: @RBZ `array_unshift` serve para adicionar um elemento ao inicio do "array". No caso pretende-se colocar `null` no inicio para ficar depois como 1º parametro do `array_map`

Comment: `array_unshift`. O `call_user_func_array` não entendi direito o que ele faz. O `array_map` ele precisa de um mapa, mas o `call_user_func_array` chama o `array_map` e usa algum mapa ?

Comment: @RBZ Já vou detalhar um pouco mais na resposta. O que o `call_user_func_array` faz é chamar o `array_map` "expandindo" cada valor do array como parâmetro. Isto é, se `$arr = [null, 1,2,3,4]` ao fazer `call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr)` iria equivaler a ter feito `array_map(null,1,2,3,4)`.

Comment: @RBZ Detalhei um pouco a resposta com explicações face a essas duas funções. Se não tiver muito claro é só dizer que eu tento detalhar um pouco mais.

Comment: Não cara, está perfeito. Atendeu a necessidade, usando as funções nativas. Muito obrigado !

Comment: Lá no exemplo do `array_map`, a linha `$b = array("um", "dois", "tres", "quatro", "cinco");` está errada, deveria ser em inglês, mas acho que a tradução da documentação traduz sem querer lá. ;)

Comment: @RBZ haha, bem apanhado. Eu nem reparei! E agora que falou nisso, tive que olhar umas 2 ou 3 vezes para reparar. Seria bom talvez sugerir essa correção na documentação oficial. De qualquer forma já acertei na resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Eu desconheço uma forma **Nativa** para fazer isso, por isso, eu fiz um exemplo que soluciona essa pergunta:

Uma forma bem básica é:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'A' => array(10,20,30),
    'B' => array(100,200,300),
    'C' => array(1000,2000,3000)
    );      

$data_new = array();
foreach($data as $key => $values)
{
    if (is_array($values))
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
        {
            $data_new[$i][] = array_shift($data[$key]);         
        }   
    }

}

print_r($data_new);
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/HTKk3u)

A partir desse exemplo pode fazer uma função para esse código:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'A' => array(10,20,30),
    'B' => array(100,200,300),
    'C' => array(1000,2000,3000)
    );

function union($data)
{
    $data_old = $data;
    $data_new = array();
    foreach($data_old as $key => $values)
    {
        if (is_array($values))
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
            {
                $data_new[$i][] = array_shift($data_old[$key]);         
            }   
        }
    }

    return ($data_new); 
}

print_r(union($data));
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/Vq7EVh)

Comment: Muito bom ! Tentei fazer por `foreach` mas não conhecia essa função `is_arrray`, aí não teve jeito. Apesar de funcionar perfeitamente, a forma do Isac, ao meu ver, é mais simples, e utiliza as funções nativas. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado ! +1

Answer (score 1):

Uma única função acredito que não existe mas você pode usar algumas juntas:

```
//Uni os array
$array = array_merge($array[0], $array[1], $array[2]);

//Ordena os array como string, assim ficará [10, 100, 1000, 20, ...]
array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);

//Divide novamente o array em partes
$array = array_chunk($array, 3);

//Resultado final
var_dump($array);
```

Documentação:

- [`array_merge`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)
- [`array_multisort`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php)
- [`array_chunk`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Não desvalorizando a sua tentativa de ajudar, a resposta parece muito frágil pois irá falhar em 3 casos: 1) valores não ordenados 2) arrays de tamanhos diferentes 3) outra quantidade de arrays

Comment: Arrays desordenados não iterferem, a função `array_multisort` vai ordenar. Em relação a quantidade de arrays pode ser feito um `array_merge` dinâmico. A única falha realmente é a divisão em vários array com `array_chunk`

Comment: A ordenação afeta devido ao `sort`. Experimente utilizar como segundo array `[25, 200, 300]` e veja o resultado que lhe dá.

Comment: Fiz o código seguindo o exemplo da pergunta, ou seja, números exatos, 10, 100, 1000, ... sei que o mesmo não é perfeito, porém acredito que será difícil encontrar algo nativo que faça o que a pergunta quer perfeitamente, de forma simples e fácil. Mostrei apenas uma opção que existe para o caso mostrado

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Como o Isac disse, se o array não for "ordenado", o que poderá ocorrer, o `array_multisort` com o `array_merge` não irá funcionar, pois iria bagunçar os dados, ordenando incorretamente. Por exemplo `'B' => array(300,200,100)`