# Como "quebrar" a variavel PHP e trazer resultados separados

Tags: php

Sou iniciante no php.

Tenho essas variaveis:

```
$tipo='a,b,c,d';
$metragem='15,18,32,44';
```

E preciso que ele traga

```
a: 15
b: 18
c: 32
d: 44
```

mas se os valores forem como esses abaixo:

```
$tipo='a,,,';
$metragem='15,,,';
```

traga apenas

```
a: 15
```

Como posso fazer? É usando explode e foreach?

Comment: Pode usar o `explode`. [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e trabalhar nisso. Como irá gerar `arrays`, é interessante esse tópico: [Unir todos os valores no mesmo nível do array, em um mesmo nível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296502/unir-todos-os-valores-no-mesmo-n%C3%ADvel-do-array-em-um-mesmo-n%C3%ADvel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentaram, você consegue fazer isso apenas com as funções `array_map` e `explode`, ainda com a `array_filter` para remover possível resultados indesejados:

```
function relacao_tipo_metragem($tipo, $metragem) {
    if ($tipo and $metragem) {
        return "{$tipo}: {$metragem}";
    }

    return null;
}

$tipo = explode(',', 'a,b,c,d');
$metragem = explode(',', '15,18,32,44');
$dados = array_filter(array_map('relacao_tipo_metragem', $tipo, $metragem));

print_r($dados);
```

Gerando o resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a: 15
    [1] => b: 18
    [2] => c: 32
    [3] => d: 44
)
```

Se um dos valores, seja tipo ou metragem, não estiver definido, a coluna será ignorada.

Comment: show, deu certinho, aí só adicionei no fim foreach($dados as $linha){echo $linha.'<br/>';}

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Você pode fazer `echo join('<br>', $dados)`. Não precisa do laço.

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma forma de fazer:

```
// Seus dados
$tipo='a,,c,d';
$metragem='15,18,,44';
// Transformando em array
$tipo = explode(",",$tipo);
$metragem = explode(",",$metragem);
// Unindo todos arrays em 1
$arr = array($tipo,$metragem);
// Ordenando
array_unshift($arr, null);
$res = call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr);

// Imprimindo
foreach($res as $v) {
    // Se algum valor é vazio
    if($v[0] != "" && $v[1] != "") {

        echo '<br>' . $v[0] . ": " . $v[1]; 
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
a: 15
d: 44
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RQAame)

[Documentação - Explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

[Unir todos os valores no mesmo nível do array, em um mesmo nível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296502/unir-todos-os-valores-no-mesmo-n%C3%ADvel-do-array-em-um-mesmo-n%C3%ADvel)

Answer (score 3):

De forma simplificada:

```
$tipo=array('a','b','c','');
$metragem=array(15,18,32,44);
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($tipo); $i++) 
    if ($tipo[$i] <> '') echo "$tipo[$i]: $metragem[$i]<br>";
```

Resultado:

```
a: 15
b: 18
c: 32
```

Comment: Rogério, se ele tiver um valor vazio em `$metragem=array(15,,32,44);` vai dar erro.

Comment: Verdade, mas como ele não especificou a origem dos arrays nem em qual situação algum elemento ficará vazio, optei por uma solução simplificada levando em consideração que somente $tipo será o indicador. Ele poderá substituir os inteiros por 0 no array $metragem em uma carga antecipada a este código.