# Como posso reorganizar este array?

Tags: php, array

Tenho  o seguinte array:

```
$array_atual = array (

    'id_item' => array('1', '3'), // 'id_item', 'id_item'
    'cantidad' => array('15', '10') // 'cantidad', 'cantidad'
);
```

Gostaria de deixá-lo da seguinte maneira:

```
$array_final (

    '0' => array('1', '15'); // 'id_item', 'cantidad'
    '1' => array('3', '10')     // 'id_item', 'cantidad'
);
```

Como posso fazer essa mudança?

Comment: Isso é basicamente uma "transposição de matriz", que eu já respondi [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296595/82711)

Answer (score 1):

Tendoem mente que as chaves sejam sempre correspondentes do array `id_item` e `cantidad`, você pode fazê-lo no seguinte modo:

```
$array_final = array();
$array_atual = array (

    'id_item' => array('1', '3'), // 'id_item', 'id_item'
    'cantidad' => array('15', '10') // 'cantidad', 'cantidad'
);

foreach($array_atual['id_item'] as $key => $value){
     $newArray = array($value, $array_atual['cantidad'][$key]);
     array_push($array_final, $newArray);
}
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xE0L7e)